# In Graph Editor, a way to frame selected, unselect keys but maintain selected channels

Tags: python, graph-editor

I often select a bone and want to "zoom in" on range of keys, and then remove the selection of keys (clutter of keyframes with handles) but keep the channels selected as they are easier to see.

[image]

and zoom in using "View>>Frame Selected"

[image]

but then I want to clean up the clutter (e.g. deselect the fcurve keyframes while still keeping the channels selected for better visibility:

[image]

above shows the result of "Select >> None" where the channels are quite dim against the background.  So then I have to again box-select the channels (or hover in the channel region and hit 'a'):

[image]

[image]

I don't see any setting to somehow change the line width of un-selected channels?   Is there a menu item I've overlooked that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it seems like this should be built-in to blender, I have created a Python script that will accomplish this (for selected bones) and will try to produce my first add-on for the Graph View menu.

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "Amature Bones, Graph View Frame Selected and unselect keyframes",
    "description": "For Amature Bones, the selected keys, Frame Selected and then unselect keys and keep the previously selected Channels",
    "author": "James Tomkinson",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 6, 2),
    "location": "Graph Editor > View",
    "warning": "", # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
    "doc_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "support": "TESTING",
    "category": "Animation",
}

def selectNreselect():
    o = bpy.context.active_object
    activeBones = o.data.bones.active
    activeFcurves = [fcurve for fcurve in o.animation_data.action.fcurves if fcurve.select and fcurve.group.name in activeBones.name ]
    print(  'remembering', activeFcurves )

    # Frame selected
    bpy.ops.graph.view_selected()
    bpy.ops.graph.select_all(action='DESELECT')  # select None
    
    # reselect channels
    for fc in activeFcurves:
        print(fc)
        fc.select = True
    return {'FINISHED'}

class MY_MT_FrameSelectNreselect(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Frame Selected and ReSelect"
    bl_idname = "graph_frame.reframe"    

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
    def execute(self, context):
        print('FrameSelectNreselect execute')
        selectNreselect()
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator( MY_MT_FrameSelectNreselect.bl_idname, text="Frame Selected, keep selected channels" )


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class( MY_MT_FrameSelectNreselect )
    bpy.types.GRAPH_MT_view.append( menu_func )

def unregister():    
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_curve_add.remove( menu_func )
    bpy.utils.unregister_class( MY_MT_FrameSelectNreselect )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]